# openpyxl adding sheets of previous file into the next file of a list of files

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, spreadsheet

Does anyone know why I get sheets 1, 2 and 3 in file 2 when it should be just sheets 4 and 5?
Also, why is there always a blank uninitialized sheet in every file that I create using the script
below?

What I am trying to do is have file 1 with sheets 1,2 and 3 and file 2 with sheets 4 and 5 ONLY.
File 1 outputs fine. file 2 is the issue as I am getting sheets 4 and 5 AND 1,2 and 3. I am also getting uninitalized blank sheets in the script below for some reason, if someone can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

lst1=["file1","file1","file1","file2","file2"]
lst2=["sheet1","sheet2","sheet3","sheet4","sheet5"]
lst3=["a","b","c","d","e"]

for i in range(5):
    sheet=wb.create_sheet(lst2[i])
    sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value=lst3[i]
    wb.save(lst1[i]+".xlsx")
```

Comment: Probably need to move `wb = openpyxl.Workbook()` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You get the blank sheets because a worksheet is created when you create a workbook. You could get rid of this by either renaming and populating the blank sheet as your first custom sheet in that workbook, or deleting that sheet after you've finished creating sheets.

Your second file has all 5 sheets because you never create a new workbook (as mentioned by @BigBen). Your loop creates three sheets, saves the workbook as `file1`, creates another two sheets on top of that and then resaves as `file2`. You need a fresh workbook for each file.

```
import openpyxl as op

lst1=["file1","file1","file1","file2","file2"]
lst2=["sheet1","sheet2","sheet3","sheet4","sheet5"]
lst3=["a","b","c","d","e"]

# Sorting file and sheet info into nested lists
files = list(set(lst1))
sheets = [[sheet for sheet, file in zip(lst2, lst1) if file == temp_file] for temp_file in files]
data = [[value for value, file in zip(lst3, lst1) if file == temp_file] for temp_file in files]

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    # Create workbook, sheets
    wb = op.Workbook()
    wb_sheets = [wb.create_sheet(sheet) for sheet in sheets[i]]
    
    # Populating sheets with data
    # Having this in a seperate for loop makes it easier to populate with more data
    for j, sheet in enumerate(wb_sheets):
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = data[i][j]

    # Deleting blank sheet
    wb.remove(wb["Sheet"])

    # Saving
    wb.save(f"{file}.xlsx")
```

Iterating through each file like above is cleaner as you are only working on one file at once. As you are likely to have much more data than in your current data list, you may need more processing etc in the second `for` loop.

Edit: Added lines to sort lists into nested lists for each file from the 1-dimensional lists provided as an input. Note that all 3 lists need to be the same length for this to work correctly

Comment: Thanks for the info @jezza_99, unfortunately, I do not have capacity to make a list of lists as the list im working with has a length of over 500, is there another way you can do this without having a list of lists?

Comment: @FadyHanna do you know prior to running how the data and sheets will be split among the files?

Comment: No. I read an excel file that provides me with a list of sheet names along with a list of files name in the same order of the list of sheets

Comment: @FadyHanna I've edited my solution accordingly